# Banco de dados para sistema de mensagens com comentarios e respostas

Tags: sql

Esta é minha primeira pergunta. e não sei se estou fazendo fazendo da forma correta. Portanto peço desculpas antecipadamente caso esteja errado.
a dúvida que tenho no momento não diz respeito a código. mas em como organizar o banco de dados em um sistema de mensagens.

Pra dar um exemplo quero que as mensagens funcionem como os posts do `FB` o usuario cria a mensagem pública e outros usuarios podem interagir com esta mensagem. A questão é, eu devo criar uma tabela mensagens e organizar por exemplo com uma coluna Status que ira definir se o texto é um post ou resposta.

OU devo criar uma tabela e nomeala pr exemplo de `[ID]_respostas` onde `ID` seria o id da mensagem principal.
É uma duvida simples. mas gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de trabalhar nesse caso.

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack. 
Antes demais, toda a estrutura do banco de dados depende muito das funcionalidades que voce quer implementar. De uma forma muito leve, voce pode ter tabela de utilizadores, posts, comentarios. Só com essas 3 voce já cosnegue criar alguma interatividade. Mas voce quer criar um chat ou tipo um feed?

Comment: Valeu! não é um chat nâo seria tipo um feed msm. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro que vc crie uma tabela para armazenar os posts e uma outra tabela pra armazenar as respostas, contendo uma chave estrangeira relacionando com a tabela de posts. Pode ainda incluir uma outra chave relacionando com a própria tabela de respostas, caso queira relacionar uma nova resposta com uma resposta já existente.